# how to use transformer in huggingface without tokenization?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I have the following code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForTokenClassification, pipeline
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/codeswitch-spaeng-lid-lince")
model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained("sagorsarker/codeswitch-spaeng-lid-lince")
pipeline = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
sentence = "some example sentence here"
results = pipeline(sentence)
```

this works fine. But instead of a `str`, I wan't to pass a `list` of tokens. How do I do that?

The reason I want to do that is, my sentences are already tokenized and simple `" ".join()` does not reproduce the sentence correctly. For example, `isn't` has been tokenized into `is` and `n't`. But a simple `" ".join()` will produce `is n't`

Comment: how did you get your input tokenized in the first place?

Comment: it was published by other researchers in CONLL format.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the original data is tokenized by NLTK, so try [NLTK detokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.treebank.html?highlight=detokenizer#nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordDetokenizer.detokenize):

```
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
toks = ['hello', ',', 'i', 'ca', "n't", 'feel', 'my', 'feet', '!', 'Help', '!', '!']
twd = TreebankWordDetokenizer()
twd.detokenize(toks)
# "hello, i can't feel my feet! Help!!"
```